# How to save a Polygon in an integrated Google Earth

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth, html5, google-earth-api

I created a Polygon in Google Earth which is integrated in my Website. Now i have to get the KML File from this Polygon. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to create the polygon in the Google Earth (not API) software, and then save it as a KML. This is because there are specific tools that allow you to save, edit, and export KML files within the Google Earth standalone software, but not in the API. All the API can do is allow some of the functions that Google Earth offers to be performed by a wider audience through certain filters and UI that the creator of the page deems necessary.

Comment: Ok thank you but i need to create it with the API.. But it does not has to be a KML file i just need the coordinates and i think i found a way to make it.